# Web sockets or Web services in iOS app development?

Tags: ios, swift, rest, sockets

So I am creating an app that communicates with my server though a REST API. As you know this works by sending POST and GET request to the server and then receiving the responses in the mobile app.. The thing is that this calls take up to 20 seconds or more to respond, even for a Log In, this makes the app reaaaally slow and I want to prevent that

So I was thinking that another option could be a Web Socket (using Socket.io). As far as I understand (never tried before) using the web socket would make the communication with my server much faster.

Do you guys have any opinions about this?

Comment: Firstly if the server is being slow then that's a limitation/feature of the server and it makes no difference how you're connecting. In my experience for a responsive server a HTTP get can get a response in just a second or two. Secondly, network traffic can and is slow, your app needs to be capable of dealing with those times when it is slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to migrate your whole REST API structure on websocket, then I suggest this would be not worth idea.

Websocket basically use to braodcast data, and whomsoever is connected to websocket they can read data and do further things.

**For example, consider like Skype, Whatsapp or other VOIP app**

If you are developing app, which has 100 users in UITableView and there is image "GREEN" "GREY" to show that user is online or offline. In that case websocket helps you.

On viewWillAppear you have to get list of all users,

Note - Though users are online ( logged in ) they have to connect to websocket and provide flag as they are online.

Now after you gets response of all users, you have to compare id from all users API response is flagged online on websocket. so you have to display "GREEN" image else "GREY".

So when any user goes logged in or logged out that users flag gets maintain on websocket, whenever you get broadcast payload do above mentioned further activity. So you would not be required to fetch each time all users API response and make them online or offline.

Basically websocket is beneficial for broadcast purpose or for some small activities. you should not trasfer whole structure load of REST API on websocket.

Think about reducing request / response time.

Comment: Thanks dude, this is what I needed. Great day